# I got a vintage roof brick that is very nice but can’t find what it is?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands, vintage

I got these parts in a lot, but can’t find any history or brand or set on them?
[image: red roof tiles lego?]

Comment: I could find more images of these roof tiles at https://www.etsy.com/listing/1074350851/ , but unfortunately no more information.