# Can someone indentify this clone brand?

Tags: clone-brands, vintage

Just bought some 12 kilos of unsorted Lego.
As usual there is some other stuff mixed up as well.
Among other things around 60 bricks of some clone brand that I have never seen before.

Mostly 4x2 and 2x2 roof-slopes in red with a couple of roof-cap pieces and some 4x2 and 2x2 bricks. Some roof pieces are dark purplish-blue.
(Edit: Later I also found some white 2x2 bricks and a black 3x2.)

The pieces are fractionally smaller (about 0.2-0.25 mm) than the corresponding Lego pieces.
You can force the bricks on top of a Lego brick, but not the other way around (at least not without risking the Lego brick to break).

The slopes have no tubes or baffles at the bottom and have very narrow studs as you can see in the picture.
The normal bricks do have baffles. 1 baffle across the 2x2 and 2 in the 4x2 (between stud 1-2 and 3-4, no baffle between 2-3).

Probably a European brand as I got these in the Netherlands.
According to the seller all the Lego is from the 80's and early 90's, which matches the included booklets and what I see from the Lego, so the clone stuff is probably from the same era.

Can anyone identify these?

[image]

Comment: Kinda a duplicate of https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/16885/i-got-a-vintage-roof-brick-that-is-very-nice-but-can-t-find-what-it-is

Comment: @IvanSanchez You are right. It is a  duplicate, but since my picture also shows the blue ones and the 4x2 and 2x2 bricks I leave my question up. The only extra information I get from that Etsi listing (if that can be trusted) is that these may actually be a lot older (1950's) than I thought.